# How do I create a class that inherits from another and passes a type parameter in CodeDom?

Tags: c#, codedom, type-parameter

Here's what I want the resulting class declaration to look like:

```
public sealed partial class Refund : DataObjectBase<Refund>
 {
}
```

}

This code (snipped):

```
targetClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration(className);
            targetClass.IsClass = true;
            targetClass.TypeAttributes =
                TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Sealed;
            targetClass.IsPartial = true; //partial so that genn'ed code can be safely modified
            targetClass.TypeParameters.Add(new CodeTypeParameter{ Name=className});
            targetClass.BaseTypes.Add(new CodeTypeReference { BaseType = "DataObjectBase", Options = CodeTypeReferenceOptions.GenericTypeParameter });
```

Produces this class declaration:

```
public sealed partial class Refund<Refund> : DataObjectBase
 {
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the following string for the BaseType should do the trick (untested):

```
"DataObjectBase`1[[Refund]]"
```

It may be possible that you need to provide a fully-qualified name for `Refund`, at least including the assembly name:

```
"DataObjectBase`1[[Refund, RefundAssembly]]"
```

And you should then remove the line `targetClass.TypeParameters.Add(...)`.

Comment: The correct line ended up being *targetClass.BaseTypes.Add(new CodeTypeReference { BaseType = "DataObjectBase`1[Refund]", Options = CodeTypeReferenceOptions.GenericTypeParameter });*

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Expressions to CodeDOM](http://linq2codedom.codeplex.com/) it could be

```
var cls = Define.Class("Refund", 
   TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Sealed, true)
   .Inherits(CodeDom.TypeRef("DataObjectBase","Refund"))
```