# What's the "`1" for in class names sent from Reflection/CodeDom/CLR?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, clr, types

I can't remember exactly where I've seen this strange `` `1 `` (single-tick and the number 1) appearing next to classnames, but it's shown up when inspecting variable values while debugging and most recently in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348268/how-do-i-create-a-class-that-inherits-from-another-and-passes-a-type-parameter-in).

```
targetClass.BaseTypes.Add(new CodeTypeReference { BaseType = "DataObjectBase`1[Refund]", Options = CodeTypeReferenceOptions.GenericTypeParameter })
```

I'm curious: where does this come from and why is it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a generic type with 1 type parameter.

For example, `List<T>` is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
```

This allows generic types to be overloaded by the number of type parameters.

Comment: +1 Yikes!  6 seconds faster - that is the closest I have ever seen two answers together!  Well played...

Comment: @Andrew: I was beat by Jon by 3 seconds, I think.

Comment: Leave it to Jon to hold the record :)

Comment: So it was just decided upon as convention? Strange that you can use a ♠ character in a classname, but not the lowly, common, single-tick

Comment: Oh, and I think you owe Andrew a Coke ;)

Comment: @Chris: Yes, the C# compiler uses this convention to generate generic type names. In the C# spec "section 2.4.2 Identifiers," the valid character classes that can be used for identifiers are specified. Backtick is not one of them.

Comment: @Chris: Sure! If I ever see him in person ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's the number of generic type parameters in CLS-compliant class names. It is needed because types can be overloaded on number of parameters; e.g.:

```
class Foo { }
class Foo<T1> { }
class Foo<T1, T2> { }
```

To distinguish these cases, compiler generates the following distinct names:

```
Foo
Foo`1
Foo`2
```

Note that while this is a CLS provider requirement, it is not a CLR requirement or limitation. As far as CLR itself is concerned, a generic type can have any name, but no two types can have the same fully qualified name. Hence the need for the backtick mangling scheme.