# Is it possible to emit a type deriving from a generic type while specifying itself as the generic type parameter?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection.emit

Imagine the following perfectly legal type hierarchy:

```
class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
}

class B : A<B>
{
  public B():base(){}
}
```

My question is given a statically compiled definition of A<> is it possible to emit the type B dynamically?

The problem is how to specify the parent type in `ModuleBuilder.DefineType`.

Or maybe there is another way to produce such a type, other than

- using the aforementioned method
- using CodeDom (which is much like creating a temporary file and passing it to csc.exe :-))

**EDIT:**
The type `B` should have explicit public default constructor invoking the default constructor inherited from `A<B>`.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348268/how-do-i-create-a-class-that-inherits-from-another-and-passes-a-type-parameter-in). I think you have the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an overload of `ModuleBuilder.DefineType` which doesn't specify a parent type, and then use the `TypeBuilder.SetParent` method to set the parent to the recursive type (using an argument something like `typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(tb)` where `tb` is your `TypeBuilder`, but I don't have a C# compiler in front of me).

**EDIT** - here's a working example, assuming you've got a `ModuleBuilder mb`.  For an empty default constructor, you don't need to use the `DefineConstructor` method at all; alternatively you could use `DefineDefaultConstructor`.  I've included an example where the base constructor is explicitly called, though, in case you have some extra logic you want to add in there.

```
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("B");
Type AB = typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(tb);
tb.SetParent(AB);
ConstructorInfo ctor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(AB, typeof(A<>).GetConstructor(new Type[] { }));
ILGenerator ilg = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { }).GetILGenerator();
ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ctor);
ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
Type t = tb.CreateType();
```

Comment: There is still a problem. Try generating the default constructor, which, of course, should invoke the base type default constructor.

Comment: DefineConstructor returns ConstructorBuilder, which is used to emit the constructor's code. One of the code statements should invoke the base type's constructor, smth like this - ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ctor); where ctor is the base type ConstructorInfo instance corresponding to the base type's constructor. The problem is how to obtain ctor? I failed.

Comment: After you have set the generic parent type with `SetParent`, try `tb.BaseType.GetConstructor()` to obtain the base type's constructor.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because I have and it fails. Go ahead, see for yourself.

Comment: Well, the default constructor will be created by default anyway (no action is required on your part).  Calling DefineDefaultConstructor explicitly also works for me...

Comment: To get a constructor that you can call explicitly from within your ILGenerator, you can use something along the lines of `var ctor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(tb), typeof(A<>).GetConstructor(new object[] {}));`.

Comment: Thanks folks. I was unaware of the static TypeBuilder.GetConstructor method.