# How to reference a static field declared in generic base class when creating subclass using emit?

Tags: .net, generics, static-members, reflection.emit

Here is the (very simplified) example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    public static SomeOtherClass MyStaticField = new SomeOtherClass(typeof(BaseClass<T>));
}

public sealed class FinalClass : BaseClass<FinalClass>
{
    static FinalClass()
    {
        MyStaticField.SomeProperty = 123;
    }
}
```

BaseClass is written in code and compiled. I need to create FinalClass in runtime using Emit. I managed to emit the class how it is discussed in [Is it possible to emit a type deriving from a generic type while specifying itself as the generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421149/is-it-possible-to-emit-a-type-deriving-from-a-generic-type-while-specifying-itse).

The problem is I can't reference the field MyStaticField when emitting. I've tried to use TypeBuilder.GetField but it doesn't work since my type is still "under construction" and it hasn't been finalized. I tried using typeof(BaseClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuildOfFinalClass) but it doesn't work for the same reason.

When I write code manually and decompile I see the reference to BaseClass.MyStaticField but I can't find the way to emit that. I don't know how to get to that FieldInfo that is needed for emit opcode function argument.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thx.

P.S. For anyone using emit... you might find this very usefull (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/emithelper.aspx). It's very old news but if you didn't know about it... try it :)

Comment: At some point you had to specify the base class... So you should still have that Type kicking around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the static `TypeBuilder.GetField` method:

```
var fieldInfo = TypeBuilder.GetField(typeof(BaseType<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuilderOfFinalClass), typeof(BaseType<>).GetField(...))
```

Comment: I haven't noticed that TypeBuilder also has static GetField method. It worked perfectly. Thx.